# How to get nodes using xpath

Tags: xpath

When I have 2 set of nodes with same element name for ex :

```
<contacts>
    <names>
      ...
    </names>
    <names>
      ...
    </names>
</contacts>
```

Normally I'd use `//contacts/names` to get the node, but how do I do if they have the same name how do I get second or first or nth?

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a complete solution and explanation of what to avoid. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this to get the first and/or second specifically:

```
//contacts/names[1]
//contacts/names[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

For the provided XML document use:

```
/contacts/names[1]
```

the above selects the first `names` element.

```
/contacts/names[2]
```

the above selects the second `names` element.

**Try to avoid using the `//` abbreviation as much as possible**, because it is usually grossly inefficient, causes all the (sub)tree roted in the context node to be traversed.

Answer (score 0):

Use //contacts/names[n] to get the nth names node. For example: //contacts/names[1] gets the first names node while //contacts/names[2] gets the second names node, etc.